# React Native state not updating through useSate Methed of React

Tags: react-native, use-state, react-native-state

what's seems to be the problem in my code,
i am createing a firestore & firebase based Application.
**Till now** everything working fine **but Now** i want to add a **unique key starting from 1 and then goes in ascending order** to **each of my item** in **firebase** through which i can **retrieve** all the items in my **FlatList Component.**
But i'm unable to do this.
There is a problem which i currently facing, that when **user fill the form** and **click** the POST Button**[Details of the POST Button is Below]** the Data is Stored in the Firebase **but the Counter** **Didn't incremented**, **After** the **Second** Attempt **(means user fill Another Form & Click on POST Button)** the Value Finally Incremented.

Means **After Two Form Fills the Counter Incremented By One** but i want to increment the **Counter** on **each of the Form Filled**.

Please Help Me!

See The Code Below

```
const [adTitle, setAdTitle] = useState('')
const [adDescription, setAdDescription] = useState('')
const [yearOfPurchase, setYearOfPurchase] = useState('')
const [price, setPrice] = useState('')
const [contactNo, setContactNo] = useState('')
const [image, setImage] = useState('')
const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0)
```

i am using these stakes in my application all other working fine the problem comes to this one.

```
const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0)
```

and Call this function when ever **user press post Button**

```
const postData = async () => {
        if (!adTitle || !adDescription || !yearOfPurchase || !price || !contactNo) {
            Alert.alert("Please fill all the Fields")
            return
        }

        try {
            getCounter();                            // <-- called this function for Counter, Details are Below
            await fireStore().collection("ads").add({
                adTitle,
                adDescription,
                yearOfPurchase,
                price,
                contactNo,
                image,
                uniqueID: counter,
                uid: Auth().currentUser.uid
            })
            Alert.alert("Item Successfully Posted..")
            setAdTitle('')
            setAdDescription('')
            setYearOfPurchase('')
            setPrice('')
            setContactNo('')
            setImage('')
        } catch (err) {
            Alert.alert("Something went wrong\nPlease try again...")
        }

}
```

on call `getCounter();` function it's **fetch** the current **counter** value **from the firebase** and then **increment that value by one** and then **update the value in firebase**

The Code of `getCounter();` Function:   ***(I think the Problem is right here in this getCounter(), But i'm unable to figure it out.)***

```
const getCounter = async () => {
        try {
            const querySnap = await fireStore().collection('Counter').doc('count').get()
            setCounter((querySnap.data().counter)+1)
        } catch(error) {
            alert("Something went wrong\n[Error]: "+ error)
        }
        try {
            await fireStore().collection('Counter').doc("count").update({
                counter: counter
            })
        } catch {
            // alert("Something went wrong\nPlease try again...")
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are trying to access a variable that was not updated yet as you try to get the updated code on the same scope.
An easy test you can do to see if that is the problem would be to change you code to something like this:

```
const getCounter = async () => {
        let newCounter = null

        try {
            const querySnap = await fireStore().collection('Counter').doc('count').get()
            newCounter = (querySnap.data().counter)+1
        } catch(error) {
            alert("Something went wrong\n[Error]: "+ error)
        }
        try {
            setCounter(newCounter)
            await fireStore().collection('Counter').doc("count").update({
                counter: newCounter
            })
        } catch {
            // alert("Something went wrong\nPlease try again...")
        }
    }
```

this way you guarantee the value you are passing to the firebase is calculated realtime before sending.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your problem lies on the fact that `setCounter` is run asynchronously and does not return a promise that you could use with async/await. In your case `getCounter` is called, triggers the `setCounter` function and then sends `counter` to firebase before `setCounter` has updated the value of `counter`.

The best solution I can imagine is using `useEffect`, as it can be used to monitor the value of counter and then trigger a function call when it is updated. So you could do the following:

```
const YourElement = () => {
   const getCounter = async () => {
        try {
            const querySnap = await fireStore().collection('Counter').doc('count').get()
            setCounter((querySnap.data().counter)+1)
        } catch(error) {
            alert("Something went wrong\n[Error]: "+ error)
        }
        try {
            await fireStore().collection('Counter').doc("count").update({
                counter: counter
            })
        } catch {
            // alert("Something went wrong\nPlease try again...")
        }
    }

   const postData = async () => {
        if (!adTitle || !adDescription || !yearOfPurchase || !price || !contactNo) {
            Alert.alert("Please fill all the Fields")
            return
        }

        try {
            getCounter()
            Alert.alert("Item Successfully Posted..")
            setAdTitle('')
            setAdDescription('')
            setYearOfPurchase('')
            setPrice('')
            setContactNo('')
            setImage('')
        } catch (err) {
            Alert.alert("Something went wrong\nPlease try again...")
        }

}

   useEffect(()=>{
      fireStore().collection("ads").add({
          adTitle,
          adDescription,
          yearOfPurchase,
          price,
          contactNo,
          image,
          uniqueID: counter,
          uid: Auth().currentUser.uid
          })},[counter])

   return <ChildElements/>
}
```

This way the data will only be sent to firebase after `counter` has been updated.

Comment: Thanks Brother, your logic not works for me, but it's helps me to figure out the actual problems. And Now the problem is Solved.... Thanks Once again